# PHP без главной INDEX.PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть папка (называется `/home/`). Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на сайт с `http://` клиента перекидывало именно туда?

Но при этом  без `index.php` (я хочу сделать так для случая, если в корневом каталоге отсутствует файл  `index.php`) чтобы перекидывало на `/home/index`.

Т.е. так, как это примерно устроено на фраемворке *Laravel* (там главный файл это `server.php` оттуда его перекидывает сразу же в папку `/public/`)

Answer (score 1):

PHP тут не при чем. Для apache можно прописать в .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 /home/index
Если в корневой папке точно не будет index файла, то можно сразу прописать Redirect permanent /home/index

Comment: В том та и проблема (.htaccess) я вообще в корне не хочу использовать.

Comment: Основным хочу сделать не корневой каталог а /home/

Comment: Тогда используйте конфиг апача (виртуального хоста) для этого. А вообще чем обусловлен отказ от любых файлов в корне?

Comment: не хочу просто засорять корневой каталог (я просто одну структуру продумал) и по этой структуре хочу пойти поэтому.  ).

Comment: **Хорошо сделаю как вы сказали, посмотрю на результаты **  Спасибо.

Comment: В вашей схеме уже видны недостатки выбранного решения. Обычно стараются как можно больше конфигурационных параметров вынести из конфига сервера для совместимости с хостингами, а Вы - наоборот.